# Loop without interaction

Tags: vba, for-loop

I have a simple for-next loop, which I would like to run(increment variable) automatically, without any clicking. In other words it should be counting to 100 automatically.

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 100
   MsgBox i    
Next i
```

Comment: Remove the MsgBox then. If you want to keep track of any variable you can use `Debug.Print i`  you will get the value in the Immediate Window.

Comment: I would like to show certainly when counting.

Comment: Like a reverse countdown.

Comment: @Santosh : I know that, but would like to see in a window.

Comment: That would run so quickly you wouldn't see the number change.  What *exactly* do you really want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a userform to do that. Create a new userform and add a label named `Label1` to it. Then add the following code to the form:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate() 'runs when form is visible
For i = 1 To 100

    Label1.Caption = i 'sets the displayed text

    t = Timer   'this loop takes one second
    While Timer - t < 1
        DoEvents    'avoids freezing while waiting
    Wend

Next
End Sub
```

Assuming your form name is `UserForm1` you can then call your userform in code like this:

```
Load UserForm1
Userform1.Show
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution!